# Is food useful?

Tags: the-witcher-2

You can purchase various items categorized as food in the inns.

Is there any use for this food? Does it restore vitality or vigor?

Comment: That's pretty silly, to have people selling an item that can only be dropped or sold back for less money.  Claiming it is for "realism" seems pretty weak...

Comment: @bwarner Claiming it is for realism, and then not being able to eat it, seems even more silly! :/

Comment: Indeed, I'll usually prefer good gameplay over good realism, and it seems an odd gameplay choice to stock vendors with gear to sell you which has no gameplay purpose.  At least "vendor trash" type objects are usually sold only, not available for purchase by the player.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Food has no effect on vigor or vitality.
You cannot even use (eat) it.

It can only be traded or dropped like any other junk item.

Answer (score 5):

Food is listed in the "Junk" category, which means, if it is not also a quest item, it has no use and can be safely sold.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some NPC's that ask for food before giving you more information. I *think* I met one in Flotsom...